# My Screen goes on First activity rather than go to main activity when I press back screen on 3rd activity kindly tell me solution?

Tags: android-intent, android-activity

I have 3 activities in my app Introductyactivity use as splash screen then Main activity where i have menu and I open 3rd activity from there.
Now i press back key the screen goes to splash screen rather than go on Main activity I also make parent activity but it does not work.

Comment: can you show onClick from menu. and maike sure you are not using finish()

Comment: Please edit your question: Post your manifest and also the code that you use in each `Activity` to launch the next `Activity`.

Comment: Removed tag `android-studio` as that tag is for questions/problems related to the Android Studio product. Your question is a generic Android question and has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: I just fixed my issue by using finish(); in my splash screen activity.